# Is Dr Manahel Thabet one of the 21 Smartest People in the World?

Tags: physics

[This list](http://www.geeksvip.com/smartest-people-in-the-world/4/) includes Dr. Manahel Thabet as one of the "21 Smartest People in the World", listing her at number nineteen.

Is she?

Comment: What list claims this? Do you have a link to it? We already have a question with answers that seem to conclude that her accomplishments are, shall we say, exaggerated.

Comment: She is at [#19 on geeksvip.com's list of "21 Smartest People in the World"](http://www.geeksvip.com/smartest-people-in-the-world/4/), which looks to be the listicle you are citing. All the info in it is taken from the intro to the now-deleted Wikipedia page about her (which is linked in the linked question).

Comment: The linked site appears to be a click-bait site with little credibility.

Comment: As an example of credibility, they claim that Philip Emeagwali received the Nobel Prize for "problem solving in the computing field". He did indeed receive the Gordon Bell Prize, which is not quite the Nobel price. Now getting the Nobel Prize for "problem solving in the computing field" would be indeed impressive, since they would have had to create that prize just for this man.